# Maximum function nesting level of '100', even though xdebug.max_nesting_level=500

Tags: php, jenkins, xdebug

I am running quite a big project on Jenkins, and everytime I try to run the tests, I got this error :

```
[exec] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

The thing, is I checked everywhere, and the solution seems to be writing :

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level=500
```

in my php.ini. I did it, restart apache but I still have the error.
Xdebug is enabled and properly installed for sure.( I ran some little project with code coverage enable and they work perfectly fine )
Also, I am working on Ubuntu.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you update all `php.ini`? Does the tests run in a browser or on command line? Tip under ubuntu cmd: `locate php.ini`

Comment: Oh, apparently there was an other php.ini, and updating the nesting level here seems to work better. The tests are currently running but this looks very promising. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Jenkins probably run the tests with php cli, not php fpm via a Web server

Comment: This is indeed workingwith php.ini from php5/cli. Thanks a lot.